# Python:Input images in a list with a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, image-processing

Is there a way to fill a list with Images through a for loop and if so how do I do that?If there is no way just show me a way to add variables through a for loop in a list and I'll take it from there

Comment: 1) a= [].....  2)   for counter in range(0:5):a.append(counter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding items to a list is straightforward

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(10):
...   l.append(i)
...
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: here is the thing I knew that because as a poor person I study from codeacademy BUT I tried it and it didn't work because I am working with images, so I decided to take the hard road and create the lists myself because I could not find the same stack of pictures for every list.But thank you for your quick response, I appreciate it.